# VB6 - WebBrowser Detect if a link has been clicked

Tags: vba, hyperlink, vb6, onclick, detect

Hi I am new to Visual Basic 6,
My application has a section which shows an advertisement. When the ad is clicked, the button "Power" is activated.

I tried to detect click on my ad that is inside a  with the id "anuncio1".

So far I've only managed to detect when you click in the WebBrowser zone but does not detect when I've clicked on a link.

Then I let my code:

```
Option Explicit
'Reference to HTML DOM
Dim WithEvents HTMLDOC As HTMLDocument
Private Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Long = 4

'Load the website directly to the ad hiding Scrollbars and focusing anchor #anuncio1
Private Sub Form_Load()

WebBrowser1.Navigate "www.traductoramixer.es#anuncio1"
Do While WebBrowser1.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.scrollBy 25, 0
WebBrowser1.Document.body.Scroll = "no"
WebBrowser1.Document.body.Style.overflow = "hidden"

End Sub

'Deteck click in WebBrowser1 zone
Private Function HTMLDOC_onclick() As Boolean
Command1.Enabled = True
End Function

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
If Not WebBrowser1.Document Is Nothing Then
    Set HTMLDOC = WebBrowser1.Document
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you:

1) create a Timer with Interval 100

2) and check WebBrowser1.LocationName string value frequently

if its value was not equal to the url your customer clicked on it, then be sure that your customer clicked on a wrong link